# How to tilt an object depending on the direction of the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

How do I correctly calculate the rotation angle so that the object dodges the player? It means that whichever side the player comes from, the object must turn away from the player depending on its direction.
I want the effect like in the video but without Joint, only rotation angle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJhiR3SOyXs

[image]

I need it for spherical map. And right now it looks like this.
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the object also have to move if it tries to doge away from the player? Or do you just want the object to face __away__ from the player?

Comment: @pixlhero No, the object will stand in place. I want the effect like in the video 
https://youtu.be/GJhiR3SOyXs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. calculate the direction Vector from player to the object.
2. calculate the axis of rotation by calculating the cross product of the direction Vector and the world up. Doing so creates a vector that is orthogonal to both, which is what we need.
3. calculate the angle by how much to rotate. This is done by clamping the distance (magnitude of direction) from 0 to the maximum effect distance and dividing it by the effect distance. Doing so creates a value from 0 to 1. However we need a value from 1 to 0, so there is no effect when the player is far away from the object and the maximum when close. To do so you simply subtract the initial value from 1. By multiplying the result with the max angle we calculate an angle in the range of 0 to maxAngle.
4. Finally we calculate the object rotation by multiplying the initial rotation with the rotation around the axis.

```csharp
[SerializeField] Transform player;
[SerializeField] float effectMaxDistance=1;
[SerializeField] float maxAngle=50;

Quaternion initialRotation;

void Start(){
  initialRotation = transfrom.rotation;
}

void Update(){
  Vector3 dir = player.position - transform.position;
  Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(dir, Vector3.up);
  float angle = (1-(Mathf.Clamp(dir.magnitude, 0 effectMaxDistance) / effectMaxDistance)) * maxAngle;
  transform.rotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);
}
```

Note that cross products and Quaternion multiplications are not commutative and need to be done in this exact order!

Bonus answer:
If you're on a sphere you need to use the normal of the ground as the up direction. Since you've probably initially rotated the tree the right way up, you could do the following:

```csharp
[SerializeField] Transform player;
[SerializeField] float effectMaxDistance=1;
[SerializeField] float maxAngle=50;

Quaternion initialRotation;
Vector3 initialUp;

void Start(){
  initialRotation = transfrom.rotation;
  initialUp = transfrom.up;
}

void Update(){
  Vector3 dir = player.position - transform.position;
  Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(dir, initialUp);
  float angle = (1-(Mathf.Clamp(dir.magnitude, 0 effectMaxDistance) / effectMaxDistance)) * maxAngle;
  transform.rotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, how to convert this to a spherical map?

Comment: @LinaDev I'm not sure what you mean with that

Comment: I have objects on a spherical map and objects that stand at the bottom of map don't always rotate away from the player because these objects are tilted

Comment: I added the screenshot how it looks like right now on the spherical map

Comment: @LinaDev here's your bonus answer. If it doesn't work for you you might wana open another question, so that other users also get the pleasure of solving your riddle.

Comment: I did it: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542801/how-to-tilt-an-object-depending-on-the-direction-of-the-player-on-a-spherical-ma)

If you know answer for my question, help me please

Comment: @LinaDev guess I'll just repost my answer then