# How to tilt an object depending on the direction of the player on a spherical map

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

How do I correctly calculate the rotation angle so that the object dodges the player? It means that whichever side the player comes from, the object must turn away from the player depending on its direction. I want the effect like in the video but without Joint, only rotation angle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJhiR3SOyXs

I have the answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73137033/how-to-tilt-an-object-depending-on-the-direction-of-the-player/73138912?noredirect=1#comment129868536_73138912):

but right now I need it for a spherical map. It looks like this right now:

[image]

I have same trees and I got different results for them:
[image]

I have correctly result for this tree:
[image]
BUT not for this tree:
[image]

The coordinates of the correctly tree:
[image]
The coordinates of the incorrectly tree (number 1):
[image]
The coordinates of the incorrectly tree (number 2):
[image]
The coordinates of the incorrectly tree (number 3):
[image]

Comment: How does your spherical world work anyway? How do you place stuff on it?

Comment: I added screenshots to my post. They are randomly located on the surface of the sphere

Comment: Does the problem only occur on that particular tree type?

Comment: No, not just this type. Correctness depends on the slope position and position on the sphere

Comment: If I give to the wrong tree transform of the correct one, then everything will work correctly

Comment: This stumps me a little. Must be something with the prefab, but I can't think of something you could do to make my script behave like this. Could you display all settings for the problem tree?

Comment: I added the screenshots to my post. Need to add something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a sphere you need to use the normal of the ground as the up direction. Since you've probably initially rotated the tree the right way up, you could do the following:

```csharp
[SerializeField] Transform player;
[SerializeField] float effectMaxDistance=1;
[SerializeField] float maxAngle=50;

Quaternion initialRotation;
Vector3 initialUp;

void Start(){
  initialRotation = transfrom.rotation;
  initialUp = transfrom.up;
}

void Update(){
  Vector3 dir = player.position - transform.position;
  Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(dir, initialUp);
  float angle = (1-(Mathf.Clamp(dir.magnitude, 0, effectMaxDistance) / effectMaxDistance)) * maxAngle;
  transform.rotation = initialRotation * Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work correctly for me anyway

Comment: @LinaDev Marking it as solved was a premature move. Always make sure to check if it works first. If something doesn't work tell the issue, so we can see if someone knows the answer.

Comment: @Voidsay Lol, mad he lost coding reputation.

Comment: @ken nah, its all good. I got a bottle of the finest copium :^) If you figure it out first you deserve it

Comment: @Voidsay well your a lot more chill than most SO users. lol

Comment: @LinaDev I figured it out. The script works perfectly fine, but it requires your tree model to stand tall without any rotation. Your problematic trees are laying on their sides and require rotation to look the right side up. The fix is easy. Change the prefab so that the tree is attached to an unrotated empty gameobject. You can then do the necessery rotations to make it look up. When you place the trees on the planet you can then turn the empty so that it lines up with the ground.

Comment: @Voidsay I thought I could do without it((

Comment: @LinaDev the alternative would be to manually set the up vector for each tree when you place them, but I wouldn't make my worst enemy do that

Comment: @Voidsay Can't we take that into account too?

Comment: @LinaDev Either Or, no mixing and I will always be on the side of automation.

Answer (score 0):

1. put a rigidbody on each bush.
2. Set the mass of each bush to 0, so it doesn't move the player (if you want it to push the player, you can set it higher)
3. Add a spring joint to your bush, and a sphere collider.
4. sphere collider should mainly cover the bush, and should touch the ground.
5. Set the connected anchor to right below your bush. (this is in local space, relative to the bush, so maybe set it to (0, -1, 0) or something close)
6. Set spring and damper, so you can customize.

If you want there to be a max stretch distance (Try spring joint first), you could use a HingeJoint, and add spring onto it

If you notice any unexpected behavior, could you please describe it. thanks :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's not for me. I wrote that I need this effect without joint.

Comment: @LinaDev Oh, why no noints? but anyways I will start work on a new answer in 8 hours or so.

Comment: @LinaDev I checked out his project, and he said he used a configurable joint to do it. Let me know if you want the details.

Comment: because I have a lot of objects in my scene for this effect and I don't want a lot of physical objects))

Comment: I use DOTween for this effect and this is much cheaper than physics

Comment: @LinaDev Unity's physics is surprisingly fatser than you may think. On a newer pc build (less than 4 years), You should be able to run 3000-4000 bushes at 60 fps. You should be able to run 1000 at 200 fps about. **You can even add a box trigger around your player, to enable or disable their physics**